# Possible display issue with my Stack Overflow profile

Tags: discussion, design, profile-page, tag-badges, badge-progress

I have found a curious issue with my profile page. If I go to [my meta profile page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4342498/nathanoliver?tab=topactivity) I get

[image]

And in the Reputation box there is an area for a next tag badge. If I go to [my main Stack Overflow profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4342498/nathanoliver?tab=topactivity) that portion of my page now has what privilege I am working on.

[image]

Is there a way I can change this or another way to get to the badge tracking screen?

Comment: I have noticed this too. I would also like to be able to track my tag status in that section (I mainly noticed this on my MSE profile).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You only get the progress bars if you have 20K+ reputation. Less than that and you see your progress to the next privilege level. Once you reach 20K there are no new privileges so there needs to be *something* there.

Not really sure why you get to see them on a child meta site - though the lack of real rep here might have something to do with it.

Comment: Is there any way to get to without having 20K+ rep?  I'm not sure how long  it's going to take me to get that.

Comment: @NathanOliver - This has been asked on Meta Stack Exchange: [Can't track Tag Badges without 20k rep?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254052/262755)

Comment: @NathanOliver - get elected moderator ;)

Comment: I was *wondering* why that "next badge" thing was so prominent.